# How to use local-name(.) within dynamic sql statement

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, dynamic-sql, sqlxml, sql-function

I have the following code to create a SQL function that will parse an XML string and create a table of key value pairs that represent the nodes and values. This works fine for me in my use cases.

```
CREATE FUNCTION XmlToKeyValue
(   
    @rootName AS varchar(256),
    @xml AS Xml
)
RETURNS @keyval TABLE ([key] varchar(max), [value] varchar(max))
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @input TABLE (XmlData XML NOT NULL)
    INSERT INTO @input VALUES(@xml)

    INSERT @keyval ([key], [value])
    SELECT
        XC.value('local-name(.)', 'varchar(max)') AS [key],
        XC.value('(.)[1]', 'varchar(max)') AS [value]
    FROM
        @input
    CROSS APPLY
        XmlData.nodes('/*[local-name()=sql:variable("@rootName")]/*') AS XT(XC)

    RETURN
END
```

What I am trying to do is have a stored procedure in my main database that will create another database with all the appropriate functions/procedures/etc. So in that stored procedure I am trying to do something like this:

```
SET @cmd = '
CREATE FUNCTION XmlToKeyValue
(   
    @rootName AS varchar(256),
    @xml AS Xml
)
RETURNS @keyval TABLE ([key] varchar(max), [value] varchar(max))
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @input TABLE (XmlData XML NOT NULL)
    INSERT INTO @input VALUES(@xml)

    INSERT @keyval ([key], [value])
    SELECT
        XC.value(''local-name(.)'', ''varchar(max)'') AS [key],
        XC.value(''(.)[1]'', ''varchar(max)'') AS [value]
    FROM
        @input
    CROSS APPLY
        XmlData.nodes(''/*[local-name()=sql:variable("@rootName")]/*'') AS XT(XC)

    RETURN
END
'
BEGIN TRY
    EXEC(N'USE '+@dbName+'; EXEC sp_executesql N''' + @cmd + '''; USE master')
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    PRINT 'Error creating XmlToKeyValue'
    Print Error_Message();
    RETURN
END CATCH
```

However, I am getting the following error that I can't figure out how to resolve.

```
Error creating XmlToKeyValue
Incorrect syntax near 'local'.
```

Can I use `local-name` in a dynamic sql statement? If not, how can I achieve my goal? Thank you.

Comment: If you `PRINT` @cmd, does it look correct?

Comment: @RickS Yes, when I print it, it is identical to the block of code that works without dynamic sql.

Comment: And you can take what is printed out and execute it in SMS?

Comment: @RickS Yes. Those were things I checked before posting.

Comment: Just as a test, try taking out the dash in local-name, so you have `localname` instead. Maybe the dash is causing you problems.

Comment: @RickS No, As far as I can tell, there is not `localname` function. Changing to that wouldn't even work without the dynamic sql.

Comment: I'm out of ideas and I'm not that familiar with local-name() function.  The only other thing I can see is that it's giving you an error exactly where you have the first single quote, seems like your statement is getting cut-off when going through sp_executesql.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not the `local-name` function. It is entirely the fact that you are concatenating in the `@cmd` variable into your Dynamic SQL without properly escaping the embedded single-quotes.

This line:

```
EXEC(N'USE '+@dbName+'; EXEC sp_executesql N''' + @cmd + '''; USE master')
```

should be:

```
SET @cmd = REPLACE(@cmd, N'''', N'''''');
EXEC(N'USE ' + @dbName + N'; EXEC sp_executesql N''' + @cmd + N''';');
```

Else you are embedding:

```
XC.value(''local-name(
```

into the string, but using the same number of escape sequences, hence the `XC.value(` now becomes the end of the string and the `local-name(.)` is technically unescaped SQL and not part of a string.

Also:

1. You don't need the `USE master` at the end of the Dynamic SQL (so I removed it).
2. You prefixed the first string literal with `N` but none of the others (I added the `N` in for the others so that they all have that prefix).